# avoid redundant conditional statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Using the following code, assume I have 5 different types that I might receive in the variable type. Instead of writing 5 conditional statements, is there a way to write one and use the variable "type" to dictate what the model is, in this case "CommentVote?" Or is this more a deficiency in the way I've designed the data model with each of those 5 things having a "vote" model?

```
 if (type == "comment")
 {
      CommentVote voteObj = db.CommentVotes
           .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID && x.CommentID == id)
           .SingleOrDefault();
      if (voteObj != null)
      {
          voteObj.Vote = vote;
          db.SaveChanges();
      }
      else
      {
          CommentVote c = new CommentVote { 
               CommentID = id, UserID = UserID, Vote = vote, DateCreated = DateTime.Now 
          };
          db.CommentVotes.Add(c);
          db.SaveChanges();
      }

      count = (db.CommentVotes.Count(x => x.CommentID == id && x.Vote == true) - db.CommentVotes.Count(x => x.CommentID == id && x.Vote == false));
 }
```

**Magic Code:** The stuff I would love to be able to do.

```
 var modelName = "";
 var modelOtherName = "";
 if (type == "comment") {
      modelName = CommentVote;
      modelOtherName = CommentVotes;
 }

      modelName voteObj = db.modelOtherName
           .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID && x.CommentID == id)
           .SingleOrDefault();
```

**Update**: I'm beginning to think my model may be crap based on some of the reading referenced bellow. So I am including some of that as a reference. Let me know if that's the problem I should be trying to solve.

```
 public class CommentVote
 {
    public int CommentVoteID { get; set; }
    public bool Vote { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 

    public int CommentID { get; set; }  //This row changes from model to model
    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }  //This row changes from model to model
 }
```

I have a handful of models that are almost identical.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to change.  Could you write some magic invented code (even if it won't compile) that shows what you'd like, in an ideal world, so that we can see what aspect of this code you're trying to avoid doing.  Also, how will the other types differ?  Is the code entirely different, mostly the same, almost exactly the same, exactly the same, or what?

Comment: I think you may be looking for a base class to define the common functionality for a save, overridden in each extended object 'type'? Maybe using a Table-Per-Type pattern? As the comment above notes, there is not really enough info to guess what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added some "magic code" I wish would work. @Matthew, I think I want to do something like you said, but I'm still learning a lot of this stuff so I'm not entirely sure what everything you said meant.

Comment: Quick overview here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx More detailed here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely reduce the code to a single statement assuming that you perform the same actions and set the same data. In this case, you should have an interface that contains the common actions and data and an object factory to instantiate the correct object based on the type.

Comment: The trick is handling it in such a way that the ORM can still perform the query.

Comment: This answer, answers the question while semao helped me identify an underlying issue, for those looking for an answer the would be better served by looking into the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you question, it more database architecture-related.

If those kind of votes are not very different from each other (in terms of properties) I woldn't use different tables for them. Instead create one Vote table with Type column and (as in the example you provided) nullable column for CommentID.

Then you can use class inheritance to reflect your votes (Vote base class and CommentedVote child class).

[Table Per Hierarchy Inheritance in Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96185/Table-Per-Hierarchy-Inheritance-in-Entity-Framewor)

**Update:**
Best is not to repeat the same propertieses in all classes. You just use inharitence like this:

```
 public abstract class Vote
 {
    public int VoteID { get; set; }
    public bool isVote { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 

    public int VoteType { get; set;} //this property specifies type of vote (e.g. VoteType=1 for CommentedVote )
 } 
 public class CommentVote : Vote
 {
    public int CommentID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }  
 }
 public class OtherVote : Vote
 {
    public int OtherID { get; set; }  
    public virtual Other Other { get; set; }  
 }
```

In [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) very good blog post you can find all possible approches. The one I'm writing about is called Table per Hierarchy (TPH).

Comment: It's worth noting that if you can't modify the data in the underlying DB, you may be able to create a view in the DB, or a stored procedure, that concats the appropriate columns of each of the tables together into this one logical table.

Comment: I can do anything I want to the datamodel, I may very well have a very poorly designed model. Reading that article, I don't understand much, everything I've done so far has been in entity framework code first.

Comment: @semao Say I used a TPH, what happens to my navigation properties in EF code first? A single vote could belong to a comment, reply, document etc. Do I even need a navigation property? See updated question with model example.

Comment: Ok, I understand the code above, but what I don't understand is what to do in the comment class e.g. public virtual ICollection<Vote> Vote creates another column called Comment_CommentID instead of using the one in the CommentVote class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it if you implement the Factory pattern with reflection, a very basic example is [shown here](http://techtaunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/factory-pattern-with-reflection-c/).

In a nutshell what you do is this: Since you have 5 different types that it could be, you would make 5 different classes that each implement a specific interface. You then create the factory class to use reflection to grab the class that is the most appropriate for your situation (be it with a straight-up class name, like in the example, or with an Attribute over the class, such as [here](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2009/06/factory-pattern-with-attributes-get-rid.html)). The factory returns an instance of that interface, which you would then just invoke the exposed method from the interface to do all of this for you.

The best part of this is that if you ever need to make another type, all you'd have to do is add another class with that attribute/name that you would be searching for in the factory. None of your other code would need to be affected, thus making you compliant with the Open/Closed Principle.

Comment: Keep in mind that he's using an ORM here, so these queries are transformed into SQL queries accessing a database, and aren't acting on objects in memory.  Thus anything you do needs to be something that the query provider is smart enough to be able to transform into a database query.  Reflection doesn't (usually) fall into that category.

Comment: In this case, though, he would move the database calls into those classes. I'm assuming that the calls needed would be pretty different from one type to another.

Comment: Nope; look at his desired code.  He wants to perform the same LINQ query, but just on a variable table. In theory you could have each of the related ORM types implement an interface, initialize an `IQueryable<thatInterface>` and then perform a static query on that, but I honestly don't know if the ORM would support it (I know some that do, and some that don't).